# map state to prop - prop is undefined

Tags: reactjs

Can someone show me how I should be using the map function correctly?  I have read the docs and tried this several ways. 
Any help would be awesome.

```
const searchResultsList = this.props.searchResults.map(function    (result){
            return (
                <li className="list-group-item">{result.urlName}</li>
            );
        });
```

Comment: You forgot `key` prop, and `li` elements must be children of `ul`, but other than that it looks fine. What is the problem?

Comment: Let me add the error I'm getting as well.

Comment: @AlexM I just added the key and the ul. Still getting the same error. I added a screen shot of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you've posted, `this.props.searchResults` is not immediately defined. You can handle this one of two ways.

Either check that the variable is not undefined before attempting to map it:

```
buildResultsList() {
    if (! this.props.searchResults) return null;

    return this.props.searchResults.map((result) => (
        <li key={result.uri} className="list-group-item">{result.urlName}</li>
    ));
}
```

Or when you map your state to props, set a default value:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        searchResults: state.search.searchResult || [],
    };
}
```

Comment: Man.. Thank you!! I completely forgot about setting the default value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use defaultProps on the component returned by `connect`and set `searchResults` to be an empty array.

replace `export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Search);` 
with:

```
let ConnectedSearch = connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Search);
ConnectedSearch.defaultProps = {
  searchResults: []
};
export default ConnectedSearch
```